# Lost luggage compensation

Tags: airlines, russia, poland, lost-luggage

I was on a flight from Moscow to Warsaw with a transit stop in Minsk, and the airlines lost my luggage. Now one month has passed, and they ignore my emails about compensation (maybe because they are a Belorussian company and they do not speak English). To whom can I complain about it? Which organization has the authority to force them to pay for my lost luggage in accordance with European law?

Or maybe someone can tell me what things I can try to find my luggage, when literally no one knows where it could be (not airlines, nor airports, nobody) But that is not the main question here; I mostly have lost hope finding it.

Comment: There is no European law or EU regulation covering compensation for your loss of luggage in this case. You *may* be entitled to compensation according to the Montreal Convention, but to enforce your claim, I would assume that you need to mandate a legal representative in Belorus.

Comment: I am assuming it was with Aeroflot? Your luggage compensation will be with your carrier, wherever you originated from. Your luggage is their responsibility. Did you contact your airlines? What did they say? I dont think you will find it, but somebody should be able to answer you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you travelled with Aeroflot you are allowed:

- 6 months for domestic flights
- 18 months for international flights

> The following documents should be attached to the claim:
>
> - statement with a list of property and the amount of monetary loss
> - original cash register receipts confirming the value of the lost property;
> - Property Irregularity Report (PIR)
> - baggage tag (original copy)
> - contact details: address, telephone number, e-mail

Please submit all claims to:
by mail - 141425, Moscow Oblast, Khimki district, Mezhdunarodnoye ave., 31, or through the nearest office of Aeroflot PJSC;

Try resubmit the complaint and if they don’t reply submit it to the [Civil Aviation Authority.](https://caaportal.icasework.com/servlet/servlets.app;jsessionid=64695317D74A76B296517405924CD009?type=Complaint&Login=false&db=v0K79J2soHE%3D&RequiresCookies=true&title=none&Login=false&csrfhash=Vf1aCkQtXCEM8a0WwxSUVQWBHWplUDtu3p3Gavo29NvFfgjT7tt-SoDgvGU93Mp2BQB1aMCoorKwoqbT8OvjJ2aYzWRf_9KsJQyIpBME4ZQzN82B-KDdwGd0PUjiA34Q2mc9YmAu1CtNolrXd3RnJa-vD_2vNWk4IfYpNh0QJDA%3D.FSTGzqasfM2sCc26kIjGEA%3D%3D%7E%21)